# Subfolders based on word in file name?

Tags: windows, automation, user-folders

I am bit of a batch file noob, so I'd really appreciate your help. I have a ton of files stored in a single directory which I wish to sort into subfolders based on the first word in their filenames. So, I have files like these:

```
C:\Folder\ABC-001
C:\Folder\ABC-002
C:\Folder\EFG-001
C:\Folder\HIJ-002
```

And I wish to move all files to subfolders based on the first word, ending up like this:

```
C:\Folder\ABC\ABC-001
C:\Folder\ABC\ABC-002
C:\Folder\EFG\EFG-001
C:\Folder\HIJ\HIJ-002
```

Please help me get out here. Thank a lot !

Comment: it not work for me or i dont how to set with the batch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The needed adjustments to the proposed duplicate are minimal:

- Use one for to iterate folder content `%%A` with a pattern containing at
  least one dash.
- Another `for /f`is needed to split the name `%%A` at the dash
- If a folder with the name of `%%B` doesn't exist create it
- Move the original file `%%A` to the subfolder `%%B`

---

```
@Echo off
PushD C:\folder
for %%A in ("*-*.*") do for /f "tokens=1* delims=-" %%B in ("%%A") do (
     If not exist "%%B" MD "%%B"
     Move "%%A" "%%B\"
)
PopD
```

Comment: Thank you very much SIR! it working now

Comment: If you find an answer helpful you should consider to [accept the answer](https://superuser.com/help/accepted-answer) and/or [vote up](https://superuser.com/help/why-vote)

Comment: @SamsonSy If that answer worked for you please mark it as correct. https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/394700